# Formatting not retain in closedXML

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am creating a XLSX file using XLWorkbook (ClosedXML.Excel).

I want to format the columns to percentage/decimal/number etc.

I have used the following

```
oSheet.Range("CL2:CL200").Style.NumberFormat.SetFormat("0.00%");
```

when I checked the excel its still showing the result as 0.2030 i.e without percentage. But when I double click the column format change to percentage (20.30%).

Why column not showing percentage when I first open the excel i.e. without double click.

How can I retain the format after creating excel in c# code

Code sample is :

```
DataTable oDataTable = GetDataTable(oData);
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    wb.Worksheets.Add(oDataTable, "Sheet1");
    wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
    wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    IXLWorksheet oSheet;
    wb.TryGetWorksheet("Sheet1", out oSheet);
    ange("B1:B200").Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left;
    oSheet.Range("C1:C200").Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left;
    oSheet.Range("D1:D200").Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left;
    oSheet.Range("CL2:CL200").Style.NumberFormat.SetFormat("0.00%");
    oSheet.Column("CL").AdjustToContents();
    wb.SaveAs(fullPath);
}
```

After double clicking I an getting the correct format as :

[image]

Comment: Do you think you could provide a [mcve] along with the steps to set up the code to run?

Comment: Edited question, DataTable have data to insert into excel

Comment: Try with the latest beta version. https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/0.95.0-beta1